# How is Batman's grappling gun always loaded and ready to use, and never runs out of ropes?

Tags: batman, technology, weapon

One of the most identifiable gadgets of Batman is the **grappling gun** ("**Bat-Rope**"): a launcher that shoots a grappling hook and enables Batman to pull himself up to the rooftops.

However, in almost all adaptations it seems that Batman has an unlimited supply of ropes. Moreover, in most adaptations, he even does not need to reload, and whenever he draws his grappling gun, it is loaded with a rope and ready for action. It is possible that he reuses most of his ropes when he pulls himself to the hook, but still - it doesn't explain how his grappling gun is always loaded and never runs out of ropes.

How is Batman's grappling gun always loaded and ready to use, and never runs out of ropes?

### Examples

Batman vs. Superman

("The Flash", 1:26 to 2:32 )

Comment: There's not just one of them.  He's Batman; he always carries at least four. :D

Comment: Is it not usually the case that the rope is always attached to the gun? Presumably there is a "quick retract" button that rewinds the rope once he's climbed up.

Comment: Can you give an example where he uses it twice? If not, the answer is that he reloads it back at the batcave.

Comment: I can. "Batman vs. Superman" - the warehouse fight scene, and the fight vs. Doomsday when he uses the grappling hook several times in a row to evade Doomsday's attacks. In "The Flash" in the pit fight scene Batman uses the grappling hook twice in a row to attack the bad guys.

Comment: I added some video references I found on YouTube, if it is not right I can remove them.

Comment: [This is why](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.knowyourmeme.com/memes/im-the-goddamn-batman).

Comment: This is similar to the cowboy hero's six shooter phenom.

Comment: Sometimes, he runs out of grappling in the DCAU universe.

Comment: _[Batman is going to need a longer grapple](https://youtu.be/_To1KOT2Pn0?t=170)_

Comment: @Adamant https://youtu.be/2aN2OU0pk-Q?t=73

Comment: Has Batman ever shot the grapple and not retract? The thing is usually used to pull himself up so naturally it can be used again after every use.

Comment: @Nelson Yes, he used the grappling to shoot a parademon in the last episode of _Justice League Unlimited_ before dumping it, because he ran out of tools to fight them. But that's another story altogether.

Comment: @Triceratops I only watched the second video, but you can see (and hear) it being retracted each time.

Comment: A core part of Batman's schtick is that he's always prepared with a gadget to solve a problem, some times played up more than at others, e.g. shark repellant spray in the batcopter. Repeated use items, like the grapple gun, always being ready is fundamental to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another answer mentioned, Batman's grappling/batline is designed to retract, which not only allows him to re-use it, but also to climb up to higher areas when needed.

Take for example these two examples from the movie *[Batman: Mystery of the Batwoman (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%3A_Mystery_of_the_Batwoman)*:

[image: Batman uses his grappling to save himself from a fall in Batman: Mystery of the Batwoman. Notice how he doesn't retrieve the grappling and it keeps going up.]

[image: Batman evades Bane's attack by using his grappling to climb up.]

Sometimes, he's also carrying spare grappling too. Notice the first image above. After he releases the grappling, it keeps going up. Because of the way it wrapped around a metallic bar, there was no way he could retrieve it, so he merely dumped it. Even so, he still had a grappling to use in the second image (which happened after the first image).

However, unlike your assumption that he always has a grappling gun ready for use, there are situations during which things don't go exactly as planned. Take for example this scene from [Justice League Unlimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_Unlimited) animated series, episode [Panic in the Sky](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Panic_in_the_Sky):

[image: Batman uses a grappling to save himself from falling off a building. But the grappling bounces off the building, and he keeps falling down.]

Batman tried using his grappling to save himself, but it bounced against the wall of the building he shot it against. Since he didn't have any spare grappling available, he kept falling down to a potential death.

The same also happened to Robin during episode [Stranded](https://teentitans.fandom.com/wiki/Stranded) of the *[Teen Titans (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Titans_(TV_series))* animated series. After he shot a monster with his grappling, he was left with an unloaded grappling, because of which he couldn't run away:

[image: Robin attempts to wrap a monster's arm with his grappling gun.]

[image: Since Robin used up his grappling gun, he could no longer use it to run away.]

Comment: The colours of the gifs look funny, because I had to heavily reduce their sizes since I extracted them straight from the videos (they weighed up to 90Mb).

Comment: "Converting GIFs to fit SE Imgur requirements" aficionado here. I'm interested in what you did to lessen the sizes of the GIFs. Did you use Gifsicle? How many colors and frames per second were those GIFs? And what other compression did you use?

Comment: @galacticninja I went on a bunch of "GIF optimizer" websites which didn't work out, then I used EZGif. At first, I tried using the "optimize" option, but it was taking so long it never finished. I ended up using the "resize" option, setting it to 20% of the width size while keeping aspect ratio. After doing that, they mostly landed between 1.3 and 1.89Mb. I think the FPS is untouched, which is why it looks too smooth.

Comment: Did you use any color reduction? Or did you just use the "resize" option?

Comment: @galacticninja Only the resize option, as far as I know.

Answer (score 6):

**The grapple gun automatically retracts and reloads, and you can actually see/hear it doing so in the videos that you posted.**  If you consider the Arkham video games to be valid sources here, then as an extreme example of this auto-reload feature in action, Batman can repeatedly fire and retract/reload the grapple gun in mid-air to glide long distances without touching the ground, and in many of the games he actually has control over the speed at which the rope retracts and can accelerate the rope retraction to boost himself higher into the air.  Because of this, there is no need to wait any significant amount of time for the grapple gun to reload and/or to use multiple ropes as you mention in your question.

Here is a video of someone playing Arkham Knight and using the grapple gun with accelerator multiple times in mid-air:

Comment: Can you add a video?