Is Batman's utility belt ever missing something he needs?
This is purely idle curiosity, but: has there ever been an instance (in any format) where Batman's utility belt doesn't contain the item he needs to solve a problem? (The answer was not obvious from a quick web search.)

He's known to run out of grappling: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/281140/how-is-batmans-grappling-gun-always-loaded-and-ready-to-use-and-never-runs-out/281314

In The Dark Knight it sure didn't have a stop-your-girlfriend-being-blown-up button.

The thing is, he would know it's not there and not look for it, so it's not made a point of.

I could certainly imagine a plot point like "oh no! I forgot to pack the Bat-cheese to distract the giant mice!"

If you are also considering running out of equipment as "missing something he needs", he used all his weaponry and even resorted to using his grappling to shoot a parademon: https://youtu.be/4GDNd8b_QOo

I vaguely remember instances of Batman suffering a defeat against a new foe, going back to his lair to better prepare, then winning the next fight thanks to new tailored gear. For instance, adding heat-insulation to his suit to confront a fire-based opponent, adding electricity-insulation to his grappling hook to confront an electricity-based opponent, etc.

@PaulD.Waite I was about to say "his parents"...

"Ay, por Dios! He's got hammerspace!"

@BenBolker Could you just imagine how many bats one would have to milk to make human-sized bat-cheese... let alone bat-cheese for giant mice!

It seems like almost any situation where Batman has a failure or setback would qualify here. He didn't have a back-brace for his first fight against Bane, he didn't have hacking equipment for his first fight against Prometheus, etc.

There was one occasion in which a bat-spine-protector would have had come in very handy indeed.

Slightly tongue-in-cheek: do you take "some days you just can't get rid of a bomb" to imply that sometimes he can get rid of a bomb, and may have EOD tools for such an occasion?

@EmilioMBumachar Bane would have a very sore knee if Batman just had a bat-spine-protector handy.

FWIW I was asking about stuff that was explicitly missing from the utility belt, not just "any equipment he needed" ...

I don't know if it was ever published, but rumour has it that he once ran out of Bat-Prophylactics at an inopportune moment.

As per ScreenRant, in Batman/Superman Vol. 2 #18 (2021) it's revealed he did not have a cauterizing iron.


Using his laser vision to cauterize Batman’s heavily wounded shoulder, Batman proceeds to pull out what is more or less an entire first aid kit from his utility belt to finish up dressing his wounds, prompting Lois to ask the question all readers constantly wonder about The Dark Knight: what doesn’t he have in that nifty belt of his? Responding with the obvious answer after Superman’s help, Batman simply answers by saying, “A cauterizing iron,” as he quickly brushes over the fact that if Supes wasn’t around to staunch the bleeding with his heat vision, Batman might not have made it out of their situation alive.


He's probably just trying to make Supes feel useful.

One must draw the line somewhere between "will I ever need this" and "this belt is getting impractical and unwieldy"...

@FreeMan: https://www.grrlpowercomic.com/archives/comic/grrl-power-428-f-u-tility/

@DavidW yes, that's the correct interpretation. I bet Batman had thermite in his belt and a screwdriver in that very moment, add both together and here you have your cauterizing iron.

@MindwinRememberMonica: That raises the point of using up a consumable item (like thermite): another reason to use something else if you have time.

He probably spends hours looking at the various things he could put into his belt, putting aside the things he doesn't need and going "nah". At the end of that time, he puts the cape, cowl and utility belt on, then looks at himself in a mirror and goes "Batmaaaan!"

Does he take out everything that doesn't spark joy?
